# How to override weblogic wlserver_10.3\server\lib\ojdbc6.jar with wlserver_10.3\server\ext\jdbc\oracle\11g\ojdbc6_g.jar

Tags: jdbc, jar, oracle11g, classpath, weblogic-10.x

I need to override weblogic wlserver_10.3\server\lib\ojdbc6.jar with wlserver_10.3\server\ext\jdbc\oracle\11g\ojdbc6_g.jar. This is to get debug logs from JDBC package.

I tried adding it in classpath (added as first jar). Didn't work.
I renamed the jar and added it here (to make sure other debug settings work). It worked. But I want to know is there any other way to do it. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had below line at the start of the startWeblogic.cmd. Moved it just above the server start. It worked.

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\~\BEA\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\ext\jdbc\oracle\11g\ojdbc6_g.jar;%CLASSPATH%;
```